pyModbusTCP packet buffer when no connection eats memory
I have a working code that I use to send ModbusTCP commands to a device that can read them and perform actions. When network is fine, it works as expected. But if link is down, the packets are stored and buffered somewhere in either the pyModbusTCP or Linux (debian 9 based) buffers, and when the connection re-establishes, are the packets are flushed, causing some unintended behaviour.
Another thing that I've noticed is that the buffer eats RAM, and I eventually run out (though the machine has only 256Mb).
The python script that generates the ModbusTCP commands is run every minute via crontab, and there is approx. 10 seconds after the run until it starts again. Is there a way to clear the buffer from either Linux commands or python script itself during this time?
I've tried having the auto close option set as True:
mb_client = ModbusClient(host=host, auto_open=True, auto_close = True, port=port, debug=False)

But the buffering still happens.

What is the “unintended behavior”?

When connection is finally made, all the Modbus messages go out as fast as possible. This lasts for up to five minutes. I have a Modbus TCP controlled light tower, that starts blinking all the messages that were supposed to show long time ago. Say I need to show red/green light based on some state of the system. The unintended behaviour would be rapid blinking of the lights in random order until the final state is achieved. You could imagine what a robot would do with that sort of volley of messages.
